# Eager load a relationship with subquery join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

i have to join a table that has relations with another table and return the result to my view in readable data and display the correct data for each user. This is my code in the controller.

This works but the data from the relations are missing, what am i doing wrong?

```
    $GetUsers = User::groupBy('id');

    $all = OngoingTasks::with(['tasksdata', 'taskstatus'])->joinSub($GetUsers, 'users', function ($join) {
        $join->on('ongoing_tasks.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
    })->get();
```

OngoingTasks has a One to Many relation with taskstatus and a One to One relation with taskdata.

User has a One to many with OngoingTasks.

Comment: Why not defining a hasOne (in OngoingTasks) on user?

Comment: How am i supposed to get the OngoingTasks relations when i do so?

Comment: What does a one to many means in your case here? One user can have many ongoing tasks?

Comment: Yes, i changed my description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an OngoingTask belongs to one user then in the `OngoingTask` model add this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And you can change the query to this:

```
OngoingTasks::with(['tasksdata', 'taskstatus', 'user'])->get();
```

If you want to get OngoingTasks based on the user ids even though the approach above would do the same, but just in case you filter for couple of users, do this instead:

```
$userIds = User::pluck('id');

$all = OngoingTasks::with(['tasksdata', 'taskstatus', 'user'])->whereIn('user_id', $userIds)->get();
```

Comment: No idea how to sort the data from this massive array. but this worked ;) thanks!

Comment: If you have many ongoing tasks take a look at paginating them. Happy coding!